# Zero division error during training a noisy speech synthesizer multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, speech-recognition

Here I am trying to train data set using clear and noisy audio files
but here I am getting this error.Please look into this and help me out.
https://github.com/breizhn/DTLN.git   all the details are available here.I am trying to run noiyspeech synthesizer multiprocessing file.

Code:

```
global clean_counter, noise_counter

if is_clean:
    source_files = params['cleanfilenames']
    idx_counter = clean_counter

else:    
    source_files = params['noisefilenames']        
    idx_counter = noise_counter


# initialize silence
silence = np.zeros(int(fs_output*silence_length))

# iterate through multiple clips until we have a long enough signal
tries_left = MAXTRIES
while remaining_length > 0 and tries_left > 0:

    # read next audio file and resample if necessary
    with idx_counter.get_lock():
        idx_counter.value += 1
        idx = idx_counter.value % np.size(source_files)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drstrange/anaconda3/envs/train_env/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/drstrange/anaconda3/envs/train_env/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "noisyspeech_synthesizer_multiprocessing.py", line 156, in main_gen
    gen_audio(True, params, filenum)
  File "noisyspeech_synthesizer_multiprocessing.py", line 124, in gen_audio
    build_audio(is_clean, params, filenum, audio_samples_length)
  File "noisyspeech_synthesizer_multiprocessing.py", line 73, in build_audio
    idx = idx_counter.value % np.size(source_files)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: No sample code, no problem description, there's not much for us to work on to help you.
Consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and fix your question accordingly.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title. Format error message - there are special functions for this when you edit question (ie. select text and press `Cltr+K`). And show code which makes this problem. But it seems it is problem with data so you should also show example data. We can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question.

Comment: message show division by zero in `... % np.size(source_files)` so you should first check what you have in `source_files` but it seems it is empty and `np.size()` gives `zero`. Maybe you should use `if/else` and check `np.size(source_files) == 0` before you divide. OR put this part in `try/except ZeroDivisionError` to catch this error

Comment: @furas Please look into it and help me.

Comment: @matszwecja better?

Comment: simply use `if/else` to skip it when `np.size(source_files) == 0` or use `try/except ZeroDivisionError` to catch error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a problem with the data-set,maximum files were corrupted.So that's why I was getting this error.Downloaded the data-set again (properly this time) now code is working fine.